# Can a sorcerer/war cleric wear plate and cast sorcerer spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, armor

So I was a sorcerer 1st, I wanna get to lvl 4, grab a feat, then multi class into cleric, specifically war for fluff reasons. Can I wear plate and still cast my sorcerer spells?

Answer (score 16):

## Yes

To be able to cast spells in armor, you must be proficient with that armor. Class does not come into it.

> You must be proficient with the armor you are wearing to cast a spell. (PH p.201)

A first level war cleric is proficient with heavy armor.

There are other restrictions regarding armor, such as strength requirements, or that a druid will not wear medium or heavy armor made of metal. But these restrictions are not directly related to spell casting.

Comment: And watch out for the Str requirement for heavy armour.

Comment: 5e: the full plate wizard is real now.

Comment: Is it obvious that the domain starting proficiencies do not fall under the starting proficiencies you don't get when multiclassing?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski see http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46760/does-multiclassing-into-cleric-grant-domain-bonus-proficiencies