# 3-level cleric dip as a Wizard

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, cleric, multi-classing

I am currently playing a level 9 divination wizard in a campaign and I am focusing on battlefield control. I am the only player in my group that values crowd control, and that's why I am focusing on it.

I've noticed that I am always holding enemies off with a concentration spell like *web*, *hypnotic pattern*, or *wall of force*. But then when it is my turn, I feel like there is no way to use a bonus action to do some damage at least and have a good action economy (besides casting a cantrip as action), because I want to keep my slots for CC spells.

Also, there is only one healer (a druid) and he is mostly focused on fighting, while I am *way* in the back line supporting. And a *lot* of enemies have fire resistance/immunity in our campaign, and most wizard spells are fire-oriented.

So I thought maybe I'd dip 3 levels into cleric and get heavy armor proficiency, *healing word* for healing, and *spiritual weapon* to have a good action economy and force damage, as well as some neat spells for my familiar.

Is this a good idea? What domain fits best to my playstyle? Is 3 levels too much?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, this sort of question isn't really a good fit for the RPG.SE format; how you want to build your character is up to you. Such questions are primarily opinion-based, and there's no way to choose a single "best" answer. This question might be better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: Welcome! How should we determine what is "best"? Best damage after you've cast a concentration spell on turn 1? Best battlefield control effects? Something else? This question would need to be narrowed down before we could give a definitive answer.

Comment: Also I'm not sure anybody has mentioned it, but you now have enough reputation to join and post in [RPG chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) where we hang out and discuss things. Feel to drop in and chat. :) We can also help with questions like these that don't fit on the site if you wanted to drop in and discuss it.

Answer (score -7):

There are a couple of problems with what you are suggesting.

First, most cleric domains have a rule saying something like this:

> When you choose this domain at 1st level, you gain proficiency with heavy armor.

You only get heavy armor proficiency from those domains if it is the very first level you take, which you didn't.

Secondly, [Bigby's Hand](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/bigbys-hand) should be available to you as a level 9 wizard and it is much better than [Spiritual Weapon](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/spiritual-weapon) although it does use a level 5 slot.

A single level of cleric might not be a bad things though as you get more cantrips and access to certain spells like cure wounds and healing word.

Comment: I know bigby's hand but I need to concentrate on it so I won't be able to do alot of CC. I'm not looking for max damage, but for damage that can be used with a bonus ability wihout having to concentrate. Also you do get heavy armour from a domain, it's not a class feature.

Comment: FWIW https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46760/does-multiclassing-into-cleric-grant-domain-bonus-proficiencies

Comment: "You only get heavy armor proficiency from those domains if it is the very first level you take, which you didn't." That's inaccurate; it refers to your class level, not your character level, as explained by the upvoted answers to the question mattdm linked.

Comment: @V2Blast Is that actually confirmed by an official ruling? You see the same kind of text in cantrips like fire bolt and that refers to character level, not class level.

Comment: @AllanMills: That's because PHB p. 164 (as of [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf)) specifies that cantrips scale off character level, not class level. In contrast, [class features](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#ClassFeatures) scale off class level: "When you gain a new level in a class, you get its features for that level." Nothing says class features rely on character level (and certainly not both character *and* class level, as your answer seems to assume), and most features would make no sense if it was assumed they did.